# create a list of word lengths for the words in original_str using the accumulation pattern

Tags: python, list

The questions is this:

Write code to create a list of word lengths for the words in original_str using the accumulation pattern and assign the answer to a variable `num_words_list`. (You should use the `len` function).

```
original_str = "The quick brown rhino jumped over the extremely lazy fox".split()
original_list = list(original_str)
num_words = len(original_list)
for i in original_list:
    print(len(i))
```

This is my output but it needs to be as a list and in the `num_words_list` variable, but I can't seem to convert it.

3
5
5
5
6
4
3
9
4
3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi I think this is what you're looking for?

```
original_str = "The quick brown rhino jumped over the extremely lazy fox".split()
original_list = list(original_str)
num_words = len(original_list)
num_words_list = []
for i in original_list:
    num_words_list.append((len(i)))

print(num_words_list)
```

Comment: don't give away a homework answer like that, it cheats OP from learning by themselves --> https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: This gives me the result I need but the assignment gives me this error: 
'list' object has no attribute 'split' 
so I think i need to use the split somewhere else?

Comment: So I got it correct by creating a new variable where I added the split and then. You helped me go in the right direction, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Without giving too much away:

1. Create an empty list before your loop
2. Instead of calling `print` on each item, add the item to the list.

Both steps should be quite easy to find online.

Good luck!

Comment: Not really happy with this answer... SO is supposed to be Q&A, and this isn't really an answer. It's more of a hint. I think you should either post a complete answer, or no answer at all.

Comment: It is an answer to a homework question. Giving the complete solution is not going to help OP becoming better. See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: I completely disagree here @Aran-Fey, OP has indicated it is a HW question and have almost completely solved it. going by this --> https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions I think this is a perfectly acceptable answer that will help OP learn as he solves the question

Comment: Wow, SO really can't make up its mind about what it wants to be... no wonder we're flooded with so much useless content...

Comment: do you really consider this useless content? OP made an effort, and came here showing they made an effort and got stuck. by providing concrete direction of how to approach this problem we are helping OP learn. isn't the point of SO to help others learn?

Comment: I appreciate any help I get from anyone, no information given to me is negative I just want to learn about python and complete my assignments because I have struggled with this questions for a while.

Comment: @aws_apprentice I never said anything about this particular question. I didn't even read all of it. I was simply commenting on SO losing track of its vision.

Comment: I don't want to get too far off track here and hijack this question, but SO is made up of its users and the users dictate the vision, hence that can change over time. I don't think helping others learn is necessarily moving away from that vision, in fact I think it helps this site grow, especially since there is already an elitist sentiment surrounding this site, I'll say no more and we can continue this in the python chatroom if you wish

Answer (score 1):

You could append each integer to an empty list, that way you should be okay :)

But a quick search in this general direction will have you figure this out in no time, best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

You could also use split() method, which transforms a string into a list of words.

```
original_str = "The quick brown rhino jumped over the extremely lazy fox."
split_str = original_str.split()
num_words_list=[]
for words in split_str:
    num_words_list.append(len(words))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same just in one line using [Python list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
original_str = "The quick brown rhino jumped over the extremely lazy fox".split()
print([len(word) for word in original_str])
```

Answer (score 1):

First split the string into a list. Then create an empty list, start a `for` loop and append the length of the words:

```py
original_str = "The quick brown rhino jumped over the extremely lazy fox"

num_words_list1 = original_str.split(" ")
num_words_list = []

for i in num_words_list1:
    num_words_list.append(len(i))

print(num_words_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
original_str = "The quick brown rhino jumped over the extremely lazy fox"
num_words_list = []
for num in original_str.split():
    num_words_list += [len(num)]


print(num_words_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
original_str = "The quick brown rhino jumped over the extremely lazy fox"


original_list = list(original_str.split())
num_words = len(original_list)
num_words_list = []
for i in original_list:
    num_words_list.append((len(i)))

print(num_words_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
original_str = "The quick brown rhino jumped over the extremely lazy fox"
abc = original_str.split(" ")
num_words_list = []
for i in abc:
    b = len(i)
    num_words_list.append(b)
print(num_words_list)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: A similar answer is already posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56710604/11952444).

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:**

```
original_str = "The quick brown rhino jumped over the extremely lazy fox"
original_list = list(original_str.split())
num_words_list = []
for i in original_list:
    num_words_list.append((len(i)))

print(num_words_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following codes as well

```
original_str = "The quick brown rhino jumped over the extremely lazy fox"
splt = original_str.split(" ")
print(splt)
count = 0
num_words_list = [] 
for i in splt:
    num_words_list.append(len(i))

print(num_words_list)
```

The output is

```
['The', 'quick', 'brown', 'rhino', 'jumped', 'over', 'the', 'extremely', 'lazy', 'fox']
[3, 5, 5, 5, 6, 4, 3, 9, 4, 3]
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
original_str = "The quick brown rhino jumped over the extremely lazy fox"
original_str_list = original_str.split()
num_words_list = []
for word in original_str_list:
    num_words_list.append(len(word))
```

#1. This is original string

#2. Here, we convert words in string to individual elements in list

#2. ['The', 'quick', 'brown', 'rhino', 'jumped', 'over', 'the', 'extremely', 'lazy', 'fox']

#3. Creating empty list to hold length of each word

#4. for loop to iterate over every element (word) in element

#4. for loop working - First it calculates length of every element in list one by one and then appends this length to num_words_list varaible